# same url ('/') with different templates based on login status in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'd like to know the best practice, how to set up routing and templates in AngularJS to show a different front & login area to visitors, and then show a dashboard to logged in users on the same base url ('/').

The two pages are structurally completely different, and also different assets are needed.

Is it better to setup two different apps for the 2 parts of the website, but then how would I manage the session between the 2?

Or is it better to make an "empty" layout with nothing between the body tags an load the different templates into that, and make separate routing for the front part and the dasboard part?

I'm looking for kind of like the way Facebook's login is made. To stay on the root domain after logging in.

I spent my afternoon Googling and searching SO, but couldn't find any guides on this. Any ideas how you usually do this kind of separation in AngularJS would be very welcome.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Martin's answer is fine, but I'd rather solve the problem with [ui-router module](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router):

1. Create three states: `root`, `dashboard` and `landing`.
2. Capture URL with `root` state and redirect to `dashboard` or `landing` depending on authorization status.
3. `dashboard` and `landing` will have `controller` and `templateUrl` defined in one place together with other application states, which is nice.

Code example:

```
angular
  .module("app", ["ui.router"])
  .value("user", {
    name: "Bob",
    id: 1,
    loggedIn: true
  })
  .config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider
      .state("root", {
        url: "",
        template: "<section ui-view></section>",
        controller: function($state, user) {
          if ($state.is("root")) $state.go(user.loggedIn ? "dashboard" : "landing");
        }
      })
      .state("landing", {
        templateUrl: "landing.html",
        controller: "LandingCtrl"
      })
      .state("dashboard", {
        templateUrl: "dashboard.html",
        controller: "DashboardCtrl"
      });
  })
  .controller("DashboardCtrl", function($scope, user, $state) {
    $scope.logout = function() {
      user.loggedIn = false;
      $state.go("root");
    }
  })
  .controller("LandingCtrl", function($scope, user, $state) {
    $scope.login = function() {
      user.loggedIn = true;
      $state.go("root");
    }
  })
```

[Complete example on Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/mAJt6JXEAp1ZdjBC5qsE?p=preview).

Comment: This is very cool and elegant way to do it! :) Exactly what I needed. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @Klaster_1 How would you go about separating the assets for the landing and the dashboard area?

Comment: What type of assets are you talking about? Static images, styles, custom directives?

Comment: @Klaster_1 this is really cool. I'm interested in doing something similar but casing on `location.hostname` instead of logged in state. It seems really doable. Basically one app that provides different functionality depending on which domain you're loading it from.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the same master template, include different partials depending on if the user is logged in or not.

```
<ng-include=" 'views/loggedout.html' " ng-if="!loggedIn"></ng-include>
<ng-include=" 'views/loggedin.html' " ng-if="loggedIn"></ng-include>
```

Comment: Great, this makes sense. Thank you. And the loggedIn boolean should be set from the controller like `$scope.loggedIn` = true; right?